# Atom error when uninstall a package

Tags: atom-editor

I got a error when I uninstall a package on Atom. Now I have the version 1.8 but I get this problem from a long time. So today I decided to uninstall all my atom for reinstall it and start new but I get the same message.

When I deleted a package I received

> Uninstalling “linter-coffeescript” failed.Hide output…
>   Failed to delete linter-coffeescript: Does not exist

But yes the packages uninstall but I need all the time to restart Atom.

I didn't touch nothing on the core of Atom that's why I don't understand. I can lived with but ....

Comment: Is `linter-coffeescript` inside `~/.atom/packages/` or `~/.atom/config.cson`?

Comment: That happen for every package, I just took this one cause want a exampler

Comment: So is the answer yeas or no?

Comment: In the `/.atom/packages/`

Comment: That means the package did not actually uninstall. Try removing it from there manually and see what happens.

Comment: Yep that uninstall, so I cannot remove packages from Atom gonna need manually all the time ?

Comment: Unfortunately it appears so. You may have better luck uninstalling with the `apm uninstall <packagename>` instead of the GUI too.

Comment: Thank for the help, gonna use apm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. Just in case that anyone has the same issue, I would like to share my solution.

#### Investigation

I found this discussion after googling around.

- https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/11464

I checked if the package in question existed in `~/.atom/packages`. In my case, it did not exist there.

```
$ atom ~/.atom/packages
```

I checked the version of my Atom editor.

```
$ atom --version
Atom    : 1.8.0
Electron: 0.36.8
Chrome  : 47.0.2526.110
Node    : 5.1.1
```

#### Solution

I just updated my Atom editor and it solved the problem in my case. Good luck.